# SOA Exam P Question: Exponential Distribution

Tags: probability-distributions, actuarial-science

Here is an Exam P problem as I have it.  That is, it was passed down to me from someone else and I am unsure if the wording is exactly as it was originally posted.  I've tried searching for this problem on various sites but cannot find a similar one.

Problem: A company insures two types of drivers: Basic and Preferred.  Basic claims come in at a rate that is exponentially distributed with a mean of 3.  Preferred claims come in at a rate that is exponentially distributed with a mean of 6.

What is the probability that the next preferred claim happens at least two days after the next basic claim given that a basic claim just happened?

Here's what I was thinking: Let $B$ be the number of days until the next basic claim happens and let $P$ be the number of days until the next preferred claim happens.  Thus $B$ ~ Exponential$\left(\frac13\right)$ and $P$ ~ Exponential$\left(\frac16\right)$.  We want to find Prob$\left(P\ge2+B|B=0\right)$.  This is where I keep getting stuck.  I'm sure this problem is relatively easy but I am not seeing it.  Any hints are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Independence of the random variables that you call $P$ and $B$ is not explicitly stated in the problem, but needs to be assumed.

We want $\Pr(P \ge 2+B)$. That is I think the natural interpretation of the phrase "the next preferred claim comes in at least two days after the *next* basic claim."  By the *memorylessness* of the exponential, the fact there has just been a basic claim does not affect the calculation.

The joint density function  of $B$ and $P$ is $\frac{1}{18}e^{-x/3}e^{-y/6}$ in the first quadrant, and $0$ elsewhere. Call this $f(x,y)$. Note we are using the variable $x$ to refer to $B$ and the variable $y$ to refer to $P$. (I would probably have called $B$ by the name $X$, and $P$ by the name $Y$.)
There are no difficulties in integrating.

Now draw a picture identifying the part of the first quadrant where the condition $P \ge 2+B$ holds. That is the part of the first quadrant that is above the line $y=2+x$. After we have done that, writing down the appropriate integral is immediate. We get 
$$\Pr(P\ge 2+B)=\int_{x=0}^\infty \left(\int_{y=2+x}^\infty f(x,y)\,dy  \right)\,dx.$$

Comment: Great.  Thank you.  I was thinking independence and "memorylessness" but I wasn't putting things together correctly.  I did the integration and obtained the solution to be 0.4776875.  Thanks again.

Comment: You are welcome. I calculated the integral, it is $\frac{2}{3}e^{-1/3}$, which agrees with your number. It is kind of funny to give an "exact" answer or one to many decimal places, since the exponential model is at best a crudely fitting one.

Comment: Ahh yes, I see.  I hate rounding like I did, but many times solution choices are rounded on Exam P so I am training myself to get into the habit.